How can I detect changes to a specific JSON attribute in Laravel using wasChanged() or other methods?
I'm working on a Laravel project where I need to detect if a specific nested attribute within a JSON column was modified after saving the model. I tried using Laravel's wasChanged method like this;
$company = Company::find(1);
$company->json_extra = ['last_comment' => 'Updated comment'];
$company->save();

if ($company->wasChanged('json_extra->last_comment')) {
   dump('changed')
}

However, this doesn't seem to work as expected. Instead, it either detects changes incorrectly or doesn’t detect them at all.
I confirmed that wasChanged works on regular attributes, just not on nested JSON attributes.
I attempted to use getOriginal('json_extra->last_comment') for a workaround, but this also doesn't provide reliable results for JSON paths.

Is wasChanged intended to work with JSON attribute paths, or is this unsupported?

Are there alternative methods in Laravel for detecting changes in a specific JSON attribute, perhaps using a combination of getOriginal or similar methods?

Do I need to compare the JSON manually, or is there a built-in way to handle this?


My setup:
Laravel 10.x
MySQL 8.x
Thanks in advance for any insights!


wasChanged() doesn't support detecting changes in specific nested JSON attributes.

You can use a manual comparison approach using getOriginal() and getAttribute() or json_decode() to detect changes in nested keys.

Model events like saved can be useful for running the comparison logic automatically.


